# Rails ActiveRecord methods in different places

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, model

I want to use activerecord methods in different places
for example

```
if ..something..
  Post.where(..something..)
else
  Post.where(..something..)
end

@posts = Post.all(:order => ..something..)
```

how is this possible?
thanks

Comment: I don't understand your question. What do you want to do?

Comment: what is something? something? i understand nothing....

Comment: @iblue I just don't want to use chained methods. I want to separate them in different places

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
if ..something..
  @posts = Post.where(..something..)
else
  @posts = Post.where(..something..)
end

@posts = @posts.all(:order => ..something..)
```

It's better to do this, in Rails 3 :

```
@posts = @posts.order(..something..)
```

Comment: I just don't want to use chaning. I want to split them